# Exception when calling a post url from retrofit android

Tags: android, post, network-programming, retrofit

I am using retrofit 1.9 for android.
The call does not succeed, and the log shows the error below.

I tried everything but all it does is returning this error.

```
10-19 23:17:10.828: D/Retrofit(31628): java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
10-19 23:17:10.828: D/Retrofit(31628):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:436)
```

I am doing a normal post request with the following parameters.

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" })
@POST("/users/request-code")
public void requestCode(@Field("phone_number") String phone_number,
        @Field("reg_id") String reg_id, @Field("provider") String provider,
        @Field("language") Integer language, Callback<UserResponse> callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked I just removed the override of content type and retrofit used this     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
and the server responded